# Why do I get classNotFound exception Although I have added my class name in manifest?

Tags: android, kotlin, classnotfoundexception, dagger-hilt

I am trying to implement Dagger hilt in my project for dependencies injection. I have
MyApplication class which extends Application ,I have added this app in manifest.xml file too   ,When I build the code every thing works fine, but when I run it my app crashes with below errors. It throws run time exception with class not found exception .

Error

```
2022-07-13 18:30:42.953 23036-23036/? E/pendencieinjec: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x28000
2022-07-13 18:30:43.414 23036-23036/com.example.dependencieinject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dependencieinject, PID: 23036
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.dependencieinject.MyApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.dependencieinject.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.dependencieinject-BKvqDel8fkOj55VnLfhHLw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.dependencieinject-BKvqDel8fkOj55VnLfhHLw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6533)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1886)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7542)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.dependencieinject.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.dependencieinject-BKvqDel8fkOj55VnLfhHLw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.dependencieinject-BKvqDel8fkOj55VnLfhHLw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1156)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1222)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6533) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1886) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:221) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7542) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/dependencieinject/Hilt_MyApplication;
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
                ... 14 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.dependencieinject.Hilt_MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.dependencieinject-BKvqDel8fkOj55VnLfhHLw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.dependencieinject-BKvqDel8fkOj55VnLfhHLw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                ... 17 more
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.dependencieinject">

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DependencieInject"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyApplication

```
package com.example.dependencieinject

import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication:Application() {
}
```

Main ACTIVITY

```
package com.example.dependencieinject

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import javax.inject.Inject

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var userRegistration: UserRegistration
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        userRegistration.registerUser("roshan@g.c","Roshan nepal")
    }
}
```

UserRegisteration

```
package com.example.dependencieinject


import android.util.Log
import javax.inject.Inject
const val TAG="UserRegistration"
class UserRegistration @Inject constructor(){

    fun registerUser(email:String,name:String){
        Log.d(TAG, "User Registration code running ")
        Log.d(TAG, "User Registered ")

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest. I think you've missed the name and the custom application class y ou created

Comment: @Narendra_Nath I have added my all source codes from my project

Comment: Have you checked this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014814/unable-to-instantiate-application-dagger-android

Comment: When I followed mentioned solution  I ran into another problem .                            `Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.`
`> A failure occurred while executing `  `org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction`
  ` > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)` @MaximM

Comment: How am I supposed to find solution to a simple bug with which I am sticked for  a week . when I use `  kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.39.1" `  I get error mentioned in previous comment  and when replace kapt with annotationProcessor like this     `annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.39.1"`  I got error mentioned in this Main Question I asked. When I try to find solution everything is concluding on  to replace kapt to annotationProcessor and vice versa.